# How can we use the structure "What + a/an + Adjective + N" for plural nouns?

Tags: word-usage, singular-vs-plural, indefinite-article

I learned this structure:

**What + a/an + *Adjective* + N**

For example,you were walking on a street and then suddenly you saw a beautiful girl, you would say:  "**What a beautiful girl**!"

But what if you saw two beautiful girls, would you then say: "**What beautiful girls!**"?

Also, what about "**scissors**: *an instrument used for cutting cloth...*([Source](https://www.google.com.vn/search?q=scissors&oq=siccor&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.2047j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8))"

Would you say: “What beautiful **scissors!**” or “What **a** beautiful **scissors!”**?

Answer (score 2):

You are correct; the right way to phrase this structure with a plural noun is:

> "What beautiful girls!"

In English, we use the definite or zero article with mass nouns, and with plurals like *girls* and *scissors,* but in this WH- exclamation we use only the zero article.

However, you have encountered a word in **scissors** which has *only* a plural form in English. Linguists call these special nouns by their Latin name *"Pluralia tantum",* (which, oddly enough, means "plural only".)

In the case of *scissors,* either of your two options is idiomatic. You will hear both

> "What beautiful scissors!"

and

> "What a beautiful scissors!"

*Scissors* is the only *plurale tantum* noun of which this is true, as far as I can determine. For the skeptical, exemplars of this peculiarity abound, as in this [**video.**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HgYOYrFchZE)

Below is a list of the most common *plural only* nouns. (A few less common ones are at the end.)

- trousers
- scissors
- tweezers
- pliers
- tongs
- means
- forceps
- shears
- shorts
- jeans
- tights
- glasses
- spectacles
- pants
- clothes
- folk
- amends
- thanks
- goggles
- panties
- riches
- annals
- remains
- suds
- vapors
- jitters
- pyjamas
- cahoots
- marginalia
- shennanigans
- loggerheads
- smithereens

Comment: I'm having difficulty reconciling with the fact that people say: "What a beautiful scissors" Do native speakers say this? Really? `a scissors`?

Comment: If they utter `What a beautiful pair of scissors` then I could go back to sleep.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Yep, they sure do. But never "What a beautiful pants". I can't explain this, and I haven't tried an ngram (which in any case doesn't comprise spoken idiomatics usages) but here it is: the [**Vox Plebis.**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HgYOYrFchZE) In any case, _peto somnus._

Comment: *Scissors* does not exist only in the plural: [a scissor](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22a+scissor%22)

Comment: Your search finds the word used _attributively._  As a noun, it has no singular, as hundreds of sources attest, e.g. [Oxford.](http://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2015/05/12-nouns-that-are-always-plurals/) (For an explanation of _attributively,_ see the entry under _scissors_ at that URL.)